# What are reasons for Durandal/Hot Towel template setting body max-width to 1100px when using Bootstrap fluid styles?

Tags: css, durandal, hottowel

It's noticeable when using the "Hot Towel" SPA template with Durandal that the views sit in a middle window that's 1100 pixels in width rather than using all the available space.

And yet all the views within the applicationHost are set to use the Bootstrap from Twitter "fluid" styles.  Effectively a hard-coded max-width set on the body tag is making all these fluid styles redundant and rather meaningless.

It's easy enough to over-ride the body style set in app.css (assumming there will be no side effects to setting it to a ridiculously high value) but I was just wondering if anybody knew the reason for setting it this way in the template, given that it's undoing all the good work of trying to implement a responsive design that all those Bootstrap "*-fluid"styles are trying to implement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No particular reason. Feel free to remove it if the layout still appeals to you. You can submit a pull request on github for changes too, as HotTowel is open source.